Create an item with 3 diferente prices
I want to create an Item with 3 different price. How can I do that thought the API, what would be the json data that I must send as body?

It is not possible for an item to have 3 different prices in its record in Xero.
When you use an item in a request eg to create a bill in Xero you can specify the price in the request as part of the body in the UnitAmount field.
